# C# Can the Console overflow with too many Writelines?

Tags: c#, console.writeline

If I have a program that performs Console.Writeline multiple times per second, and the program is left running for a long period of time, can the console overflow with too many lines? I just want to know if it will eventually throw an IO exception or if number of Console.Writelines is virtually infinite.

Comment: There must be reason you asked this question, so what is it, people don't ask random questions.

Comment: Not really relevant to your question, but thought it would be worth mentioning that it might not be great practise to use Console.Writeline many times per second unless you need to. There is a heavy I/O cost associated with writing to the console which may in fact be slowing your program down.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

No, it won't overflow. If you check the *Options* tab for a shortcut to the command window you will see a *buffer size* option. This specifies the maximum number of lines that will be stored. Older ones get deleted.

As Scott suggests in his comment below, you can access this setting from your code using [`Console.BufferHeight`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.bufferheight.aspx). The default value for this (when I tested on my development PC) is **300**. The maximum allowed value is **32766** (`Int16.MaxValue - 1`).

Comment: Or just check/set `Console.BufferHeight`

Answer (score 4):

The console has a buffer of how many lines it keeps, you can set it in the cmd.exe properties:

[image: Cmd.exe properties]

So after 300 lines it will forget what was output at line 1.

Answer (score 1):

the maximum allowed value is 32766 (corrected);