# Embed console in form

Tags: vb.net, string, logging, server

**TL;DR**:

Is there a way to embed a console inside a form, so it becomes a part of it?

---

**Scenario**:

I am writing a chat-application with `client`, `server` and `database` using Windows Forms in VB.NET. The server should `log all communication` it has `with clients` in a `textbox`.

---

**The Problem**:

So far that would not be a problem - If there wasn't a `maxlength for strings`! I expect this server to almost never stop (Okay, there is always some point where it does.. but lets ignore that). So if i go for `Textbox1.Text &= vbnewline & "Something"` it will some day reach this length and run into an `exception` each time something is about to be logged. I also don't want to just remove the first characters of the string.

---

**My Idea for a solution**:

My idea for a work around: `Use a console` instead of a simple textbox and `embed it into the form`, so it becomes a part of it. Is there a simple way to do that? By simple I mean that I should have to write thousands of lines of code to achieve that goal.

I am open minded for different ideas and ways to do so as well.

Comment: Not much point putting the TL:DR at the end of your question ;-)

Comment: @MattWilko good point.. I agree

Comment: It's not clear how using a console would solve your problem anyway; or alternatively what exactly do you mean by 'console' ?

Comment: The console has a much smaller maxlength than a normal string object. You should store the last 1000 message or something on the screen and the rest let it be logged in a file.

Comment: A console (Win + R -> cmd) handles its full content as a single string? Almost hard to believe for me tbh.

Comment: No. This is not possible. A console cannot be embedded in a form. You will need to solve the actual problem that is preventing you from using a textbox. Keep in mind that no user will ever read enough text to reach a textbox's maximum length. If you're holding a gun to their head while they read, consider using a RichTextBox.

Comment: @CodyGray Going to use 2 guns then! Guess Matt Wilkos solution was the best yet.

Comment: console has a max length of 32766 so it won't solve your solution anyway: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11363552/c-sharp-can-the-console-overflow-with-too-many-writelines

Comment: @MattWilko This is the most on point answer ever. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just log your chat to file (you could create a file per day)?

```
    Dim filename = String.Format("C:\Temp\{0:yyyy-MM-dd}-log.txt", DateTime.Now)
    My.Computer.FileSystem.WriteAllText(filename, "line of text", True)
```

Then to display it - use a `ListBox` and append each new line to the end of the listbox? Each time you append, you could check how many items are in the listbox and remove the first 100 if you are over 1000 as an example.

Comment: Wouldn't the file someday become way to huge for any editor to open? Once there are to many characters in a file most editors have huge troubles opening it.

Comment: Definitly a way to do it. Had similar thoughts already as well. If i can't find another way to do it I will use it. But I am still interested if there is a way to embed a console in the form.

Comment: @Luke you could have 1 file per day